# aws_wafv2_web_acl is not working in steampipe

Tags: steampipe

I am using Steampipe to query the information from my AWS account.

my `~/.steampipe/config/aws.spc` has the following content:

```
connection "aws" {
  plugin  = "aws"
  profile = "xxxxx"
  regions = ["*"]
}
```

and I am using the following query to get the results:

```sql
select
  name,
  id
from
  aws_wafv2_web_acl
where
  scope = 'CLOUDFRONT';
```

And I have received the 0 results. i.e.:

```
+------+----+
| name | id |
+------+----+
+------+----+
```

Despite that, there are 2 WAFv2 ACL exist.

This works perfect when I query using AWS CLI:

```bash
aws wafv2 list-web-acls --scope CLOUDFRONT --profile xxxx
```

In my config, I have tried changing the region to "us-east-1", but still, no luck.

I would like to know if this has worked for anybody.

Any help in this matter would be highly appreciated.